# How would I put multiple Facebook tracking pixels on one web page?

Tags: javascript, facebook

We are trying to use Facebook's Ad tracking pixels to track ads.
we looked at Facebook's documentation and that led me no where.

I need to know how to trigger multiple Facebook pixels on one page because we have multiple ads running.

I took the code that it gave me per pixel and placed it on the page and then we have a Cart page in which I fire or add the 'Purchase' event.  But since I have the script 3 times it seems to fire 3 times. I want it to fire once per pixel.

This is what I have so far:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code - Ad 1-->
 <script>
 !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
 n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
 n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
 t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
 document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

 fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx12');
 fbq('track', "PageView");
 // Purchase
 // Track purchases or checkout flow completions (ex. landing on "Thank You" or confirmation page)
 fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '1.00', currency: 'USD'});
 </script>
 <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
 src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx12&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
  /></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->

 <!-- Facebook Pixel Code - Ad 2-->
 <script>
 !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
 n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
 n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
 t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
 document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

 fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx34');
 fbq('track', "PageView");
 // Purchase
 // Track purchases or checkout flow completions (ex. landing on "Thank You" or confirmation page)
 fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '1.00', currency: 'USD'});

 </script>
 <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
 src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx34&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
  /></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->

 <!-- Facebook Pixel Code - Ad 2-->
 <script>
 !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
 n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
 n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
 t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
 document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

 fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx56');
 fbq('track', "PageView");
 // Purchase
 // Track purchases or checkout flow completions (ex. landing on "Thank You" or confirmation page)
 fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '1.00', currency: 'USD'});
 </script>
 <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
 src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx56&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
  /></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Is this the way to do it?  Or do I need to do something different so that the Purchase event does not get fired 4 times. I am using the FB Pixel Helper plugin for Chrome to make sure all pixels are firing, but I am getting an error that they are firing multiple times.

**Would I do something like this?**

```
 <!-- Facebook Pixel Code - ALL ADS-->
 <script>
 !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
 n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
 n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
 t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
 document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

 fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx12');
 fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx34');
 fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx56');
 fbq('track', "PageView");
 // Purchase
 // Track purchases or checkout flow completions (ex. landing on "Thank You" or confirmation page)
 fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '1.00', currency: 'USD'});
 </script>
 <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
 src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx12&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
  /></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: I’ve literally just tried this out, with the multiple init calls, it seems to be working (no errors in the chrome helper) but I'll update here later when the client confirms if ti is or not!

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 16):

I was running into the same problem and I couldn't find the solution anywhere.  I dug into the code and found a method you can used called "addPixelId".  In my testing, you can use this right after the "init", which will add a second ID.  Any events you track will now send to both IDs.  For example:

```
fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx12');
fbq('addPixelId', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx34');
fbq('addPixelId', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx56');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
```

The only other thing to be aware of is any events you track will be tracked for all IDs that you have defined.  It's been working fantastic for me, no issues whatsoever.

Comment: The [source code](https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js), shows that the `init` and `addPixelId` methods are actually doing the same thing. The downside to using `addPixelId` is you'll get a warning "Multiple pixels with conflicting versions were detected". I'd imagine that Facebook is trying to deprecate this method, so it's probably best to go with the solution suggested by the OP.

Comment: @AaronBlenkush — That warning appears when using both `init` and `addPixelId` at the time of this comment.

Comment: That's right. You don't need `addPixelId`. Just use `init`.

Answer (score 5):

Simply put in one JS file this code:
        //Facebook Multi-Pixel

```
    (function() {
        var fbq = (function() {
            function fbq()
            {
                if(arguments.length > 0) {
                    var action, pixel_id, type_track, content_obj;

                if( typeof arguments[0] == "string") action = arguments[0];
                if( typeof arguments[1] == "string") pixel_id = arguments[1];
                if( typeof arguments[2] == "string") type_track = arguments[2];
                if( typeof arguments[3] == "object") content_obj = arguments[3];

                var params = [];
                if(typeof action == "string" && action.replace(/\s+/gi, "") != "" && 
                   typeof pixel_id == "string" && pixel_id.replace(/\s+/gi, "") != "" &&
                   typeof type_track == "string" && type_track.replace(/\s+/gi, "")) {

                    params.push("id=" + encodeURIComponent(pixel_id));
                    switch(type_track) {
                        case "PageView":
                        case "ViewContent":
                        case "Search":
                        case "AddToCart":
                        case "InitiateCheckout":
                        case "AddPaymentInfo":
                        case "Lead":
                        case "CompleteRegistration":
                        case "Purchase":
                        case "AddToWishlist":
                            params.push("ev=" + encodeURIComponent(type_track));
                            break;
                        default:
                            return;
                    }

                    params.push("dl=" + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href));
                    params.push("rl=" + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer));
                    params.push("if=false");
                    params.push("ts=" + new Date().getTime());

                    if(typeof content_obj == "object") {
                        for(var u in content_obj) {
                            if(typeof content_obj[u] == "object" && content_obj[u] instanceof Array) {
                                if(content_obj[u].length > 0) {
                                    for(var y=0; y<content_obj[u].length; y++) { content_obj[u][y] = (content_obj[u][y]+"").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gi, "").replace(/\s+/gi," ").replace(/,/gi, "§"); }
                                    params.push("cd[" + u + "]=" + encodeURIComponent(content_obj[u].join(",").replace(/^/gi, "[\"").replace(/$/gi, "\"]").replace(/,/gi, "\",\"").replace(/§/gi, "\,")));
                                }
                            }
                            else if(typeof content_obj[u] == "string")
                                params.push("cd[" + u + "]=" + encodeURIComponent(content_obj[u]));
                        }
                    }

                    params.push("v=" + encodeURIComponent("2.5.0"));                                

                    if(typeof window.jQuery == "function") {
                        var iframe_id = new Date().getTime();
                        jQuery("body").append("<img height='1' width='1' style='display:none;width:1px;height:1px;' id='fb_" + iframe_id + "' src='https://www.facebook.com/tr/?" + params.join("&") + "' />");
                        setTimeout(function() { jQuery("#fb_" + iframe_id).remove(); }, 1000);
                    }




                }


            }
        }

    return fbq;
    });

window.fbq = new fbq();
})();
```

And than, usage example:

```
fbq('track', "<PIXEL_ID>", "PageView");

fbq('track", "<PIXEL_ID>", "ViewContent", {
                 content_name: "name test",
                 content_category: "category test",
                 content_ids: ["test"],
                 content_type: "product",
                 value: 7.99,
                 currency: "GBP"
          });
```

and so on.

Answer (score 4):

This is the current working approach that I recommend based on Facebook source code (based on https://developers.facebook.com/). Use the "init" function multiple times, that simple...

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '158xxxxxxxxxx911');
fbq('init', '180xxxxxxxxxx762');
fbq('init', '125xxxxxxxxxx694');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=180xxxxxxxxxx762&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: Can you reference where does facebook recommend this?

Comment: @ThangPham my previous answer was misleading. I cannot find anywhere that Facebook recommends any approach to multiple pixel tracking in one page. Thus, I've devised this code approach based on Facebook's source code and have proven it working in my own multiple-pixel environments.

Comment: This code approach is in use by Facebook Developers Team and can be referenced by viewing page source code here: https://developers.facebook.com/ -- Note how they only use 1 img pixel as well -- not multiple images.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the Facebook Pixel code/initialization can take a little bit of time to load not to mention a user's connection and device will also affect the init time.

You DO NOT want to paste the code three times.

First call the core FB JS Pixel code that references the `fbevents.js` library

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){    
n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];
t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document, 'script',    
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
```

Then create your array of pixel ids

```
// Array of FB PixelIDs
var pixel_ids = ['xxx111','xxx222'];
```

Iterate over the array and call each pixel initialization with a small delay. I'd tweak it to meet your needs. You'll need to use a closure function to ensure the proper value of your array is assigned.

```
// Iterate over the ids and ensure each one is initialized
for (var i = 1; i <= pixel_ids.length; i++){
  // Add delay here to allow each pixel to instantiate
  setTimeout(function(x) { return function() {fbq('init',x.toString());};
    }(pixel_ids[i-1]), 33*i);
}
```

Now it's time to call your actual tracking events **also with a delay** to ensure they are fired after pixel initialization.

```
setTimeout(function() { fbq('track', "PageView");}, (33*pixel_ids.length)+33);
setTimeout(function() { fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '1.00', currency: 'USD'});},(33*pixel_ids.length)+66);
```

For good measure put a HTML no script call to `PageView` for each pixel

```
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"   
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxx111&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"   
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxx2222&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
```

The number of events fired should equal the number of pixels you have times the number of events (i.e. each event registered for each pixel) ... there should not be errors if you implement right.

Comment: The timeouts are not necessary.  Facebook's code is asynchronous, meaning that once you create the fbq function (the code you add to the page), it doesn't matter whether or not the Facebook JS code has already loaded.  If the code hasn't loaded, it pushes items to an array, and once the code has loaded it will parse the array and then the code will just execute immediately.  It's similar to how Google Analytics works.

Answer (score 2):

@ClosDesign, you're on the right track! As you suspected, you can call `fbq('init', '[your-pixel-id]')` multiple times, which adds each pixel ID to the list of IDs that all events will be tracked to. I wrote a [blog post](http://washamdev.com/multiple-facebook-pixels-on-one-site/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=35926833) about this issue of using multiple Facebook pixels on one site, so read there for more details.

Using your example code, you first want to include Facebook's JavaScript pixel code. This will load the JavaScript from Facebook that is needed to send pixel events with their `fbq` object:

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
```

Then, it's time to `init` all pixel IDs:

```
fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx12');
fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx34');
fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx56');
```

Once you have initialized all the pixel IDs on your site with `fbq('init')`, use the [Facebook Pixel Helper](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/pixel-helper) to confirm all pixels have been loaded. You can also manually confirm they have been loaded by running the following code in the JavaScript console:

```
fbq.getState().pixels
```

After that, any calls you make to `track` an event will be tracked to all pixel IDs you initialized above. So if you call:

```
fbq('track', "PageView");
```

A `PageView` event will be sent to Facebook for all three pixels. Your `Purchase` event works the same way.

When it comes to the `<noscript>` tags Facebook includes, you would need to include an `<img>` tag for each pixel ID you want to call on your site:

```
<noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx12&ev=PageView&noscript=1" />
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx34&ev=PageView&noscript=1" />
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx56&ev=PageView&noscript=1" />
</noscript>
```

Note that if the user has JavaScript turned off, those `<img>` tags only send a request to Facebook to track a `PageView` event. The `Purchase` event will not be tracked unless you create another `<img>` tag for each pixel ID and specify data for tracking the `Purchase` event also.

A natural next question is, "Can I track an event to only one of many pixels initialized on my site?" Not using Facebook's `fbq` object, no.

There is a [workaround](http://washamdev.com/multiple-facebook-pixels-on-one-site/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=35926833) to this, however. Using the `<img>` tag method above, you can send events to Facebook and only track the event to one pixel ID. This method bypasses the `fbq` object entirely and dynamically builds an `<img>` tag with the event information you specify.

### Code

```
(function (window, document) {
    if (window.myfbq) return;
    window.myfbq = (function () {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            var pixelId, trackType, contentObj;

            if (typeof arguments[0] == 'string') pixelId = arguments[0];
            if (typeof arguments[1] == 'string') trackType = arguments[1];
            if (typeof arguments[2] == 'object') contentObj = arguments[2];

            var params = [];
            if (typeof pixelId === 'string' && pixelId.replace(/\s+/gi, '') != '' &&
            typeof trackType === 'string' && trackType.replace(/\s+/gi, '')) {
                params.push('id=' + encodeURIComponent(pixelId));
                switch (trackType) {
                    case 'PageView':
                    case 'ViewContent':
                    case 'Search':
                    case 'AddToCart':
                    case 'InitiateCheckout':
                    case 'AddPaymentInfo':
                    case 'Lead':
                    case 'CompleteRegistration':
                    case 'Purchase':
                    case 'AddToWishlist':
                        params.push('ev=' + encodeURIComponent(trackType));
                        break;
                    default:
                        return;
                }

                params.push('dl=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href));
                if (document.referrer) params.push('rl=' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer));
                params.push('if=false');
                params.push('ts=' + new Date().getTime());

                if (typeof contentObj == 'object') {
                    for (var u in contentObj) {
                        if (typeof contentObj[u] == 'object' && contentObj[u] instanceof Array) {
                            if (contentObj[u].length > 0) {
                                for (var y = 0; y < contentObj[u].length; y++) { contentObj[u][y] = (contentObj[u][y] + '').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gi, '').replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').replace(/,/gi, '§'); }
                                params.push('cd[' + u + ']=' + encodeURIComponent(contentObj[u].join(',').replace(/^/gi, '[\'').replace(/$/gi, '\']').replace(/,/gi, '\',\'').replace(/§/gi, '\,')));
                            }
                        }
                        else if (typeof contentObj[u] == 'string')
                            params.push('cd[' + u + ']=' + encodeURIComponent(contentObj[u]));
                    }
                }

                params.push('v=' + encodeURIComponent('2.7.19'));

                var imgId = new Date().getTime();
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.id = 'fb_' + imgId, img.src = 'https://www.facebook.com/tr/?' + params.join('&'), img.width = 1, img.height = 1, img.style = 'display:none;';
                document.body.appendChild(img);
                window.setTimeout(function () { var t = document.getElementById('fb_' + imgId); t.parentElement.removeChild(t); }, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
})(window, document);
```

### Usage

```
myfbq("[your-pixel-id]", "PageView");
myfbq("[your-pixel-id]", "ViewContent");
myfbq("[your-pixel-id]", "ViewContent", { content_type: "product", content_ids: ['892185001003'] });
```

Comment: Hi. I know it's been a while since this question was made, but what does `2.7.19` means on this line: `params.push('v=' + encodeURIComponent('2.7.19'));`  I guess it's a version, but from what? I guess I should use the latest version if I want to use FB latests updates. Any guess?

Comment: @NestorVillalobos Correct. That specific param is specifying a version number. 2.7.19 is the version number I saw from `fbq` events I saw firing before I built my script, so that's the one I specified in my script. If you are seeing a more recent version number, feel free to try. Although if they've changed functionality since 2.7.19, you made need to add some additional properties that they now require or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

One other solution would be just to use the no-javascript approach if you want to track only certain events for certain pixel IDs

You can see some examples in their docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/api-reference

```
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=FB_PIXEL_ID&amp;ev=MyCustomEvent&amp;cd[custom_param]=custom_value"
/>

<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=FB_PIXEL_ID&amp;ev=PageView&amp;noscript=1"
/>
```

You just need to get the parameter formatting right.

Answer (score 1):

According to FB's recommendation, it's very easy to track different events to different pixels:

```
fbq('trackSingle', 'FB_PIXEL_ID', 'Purchase', customData);
fbq('trackSingleCustom', 'FB_PIXEL_ID', 'CustomEvent', customData);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/api-reference#tracking-events-for-individual-pixels

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to give the most up-to-date link in their documentation for using multiple pixels on a page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/advanced#multipixels

Here is the code example:

```
fbq('init', '<PIXEL_A>');
fbq('init', '<PIXEL_B>');
fbq('track', 'PageView'); //fire PageView for both initialized pixels

// only fire the Purchase event for Pixel A
fbq('trackSingle', '<PIXEL_A>', 'Purchase', {
      value: 4,
      currency: 'GBP',
});

// only fire the custom event Step4 for Pixel B
fbq('trackSingleCustom', '<PIXEL_B>', 'Step4',{
  //optional parameters
});
```